# Parse Server Swift Logic for grabbing all items contained in array

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I am using parse server with Swift. I am trying to get all matches that where the key "username" is contained in commentUserArray. Comment userArray displays 3 names ["username","username", "username2"].

The query grabs only two values as opposed to three as this looks up only for those two usernames "username" and "username1". However, I need all 3 instances of this. Please help.

```
   var commentImgUrlArray: [NSString] = []

   func getPics(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", containedIn: commentUserArray)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                    let imageFile = object["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
                    let imageFileString = imageFile?.url as! String
                    if let url = URL(string: imageFileString) {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                        if let imageData = data {
                            self.commentImgUrlArray.append(imageFileString as NSString)
                            print(self.commentImgUrlArray)
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                completionHandler()
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error, I have come across the solution.

1. Delete the original query.contained in as that overrides the rest of the formula.
2. Ideally, I want to run one query. Not however many on in commentuserarray. As a result, the for in loop should be placed inside the query.find -->
3. need to grab object for that specific user. Therefore, let pfuser = object["username"] as String
4. reverse the array to get the proper order --

   ```
    func getPics(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: 
    Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                    for user in self.commentUserArray {
                    let pfuser = object["username"] as! String
                    if pfuser == user {
                    let imageFile = object["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
                    let imageFileString = imageFile?.url as! String
                    if let url = URL(string: imageFileString) {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                        if let imageData = data {
                            self.commentImgUrlArray.append(imageFileString as 
                          NSString)
                            print(self.commentImgUrlArray)
                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.commentImgUrlArray.reverse()
                completionHandler()
            }
    })
   ```

   }